# Access Forbidden Project

Tags: php, laravel

I am just a new laravel student(self study)

I'd updated the xampp to the latest and I got this error when tried to open my project

```
Access forbidden!
You don't have permission to access the requested object. It is either read-protected or not readable by the server.
If you think this is a server error, please contact the webmaster.
Error 403
localhost
Apache/2.4.41 (Unix) OpenSSL/1.1.1c PHP/7.1.32 mod_perl/2.0.8-dev Perl/v5.16.3
```

I already tried this but still doesn't working

```
sudo chmod -R 777 storage

sudo chmod -R 777 bootstrap
```

Help me please.. What to do?

Comment: Laravel has both Valet and Homestead, why do you make life harder on yourself?

Comment: Have you setup permissions for app directory first ?

Answer (score 1):

You can run laravel using the command: "`php artisan serve`". This way you don't need XAMPP apache. Or if you want to run it from apache you have to point it into laravel public folder.